# Complicated regex with numbers and group of numbers

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have this strings like this one as input:

```
(1,3,4,(3,4,21),55,69,12,(3,8),9)
```

and I would like to have this output, as an array or a list of strings

```
1 - 3 - 4 - (3,4,21) - 55 - 69 - 12 - (3,8) - 9
```

Could someone help? I've tried a couple regex but had no luck.

EDIT: Please note that the "-" in the output represents a different element of the same array or list, not a desidered character.

Example: array[0]="1"; array[1]="3"; array[3]="(3,4,21)";

Comment: I'd advise against using regex for this.

Comment: Yeah...write a parser.

Comment: Should be there space between '-' and 69 in output?

Comment: Just edited my question, thanks Pzremyslaw Moskal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try this regex:

```
,(?!(?:(?:[^\(\)]*[\(\)]){2})*[^\(\)]*$)
```

This will match all the commas(,) that should be replaced by - 
or you may split by the above regex as well

**Explanation**:

The logic is to find a comma that is not followed by even numbers of brackets **(** and **)**

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/r12uPg/3/)

Sample Source ( [run here](https://ideone.com/lWlBdi) ):

```
final String regex = ",(?!(?:(?:[^\\(\\)]*[\\(\\)]){2})*[^\\(\\)]*$)";
final String string = "(1,3,4,(3,4,21),55,69,12,(3,8),9)";

String[] result=string.split(regex);
int len=result.length;
for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
{

// the following two if condition is necessary to remove the start and end brace
// many other and probably better alternatives could be there to remove it 

 if(result[i].contains("(") && !result[i].contains(")"))
  result[i]=result[i].replace("(","");
 else if(result[i].contains(")") && !result[i].contains("("))
  result[i]=result[i].replace(")","");   
}

System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(result));
```

Output:

```
[1, 3, 4, (3,4,21), 55, 69, 12, (3,8), 9]
```